Transmission line current-voltage explicit relation in time domain
Consider an electrical transmission line with usual parameters $R,G,L,C$.
I have been going through telegraph(er) equations and their general solution over the last few days and Fourier transformed solutions are easy to obtain:
$$V(\omega,z)=A(\omega)e^{\gamma z}+B(\omega)e^{-\gamma z}$$
$$I(\omega,z)=Y(\omega) V(\omega,z)$$
$$\gamma = \sqrt{(R+i\omega L)(G+i \omega C)}$$
$$Y(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{G+i\omega C}{R+i \omega L}}$$
This is all known stuff.
Now here's my question. I really wanted to derive the time-domain relationship between current and voltage, and so I tried to find inverse Fourier transform of $Y(\omega)$, assuming of course that all the parameters don't depend on frequency (not true at high frequencies, but bear with me).
Using binomial series expansion, I obtained the inverse Fourier transform as follows:
$$Y(t)=\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} \left(\delta(t)- \eta \theta (-t) e^{\nu t} \left[I_0(\eta t)+I_1(\eta t) \right] \right) \tag{1}$$
Where $\theta$ is Heaviside function, $\eta= \frac{RC-GL}{2LC}$, $\nu= \frac{RC+GL}{2LC}>0$, $I_0,I_1$ - modified Bessel functions.
Using this result, I obtained explicitly:
$$I(t,z)=\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} \left(V(t,z)- \eta \int_0^\infty V(t-t',z) e^{-\nu t'} \left[I_0(-\eta t')+I_1(-\eta t') \right] dt' \right) \tag{2}$$
This obeys the causality rule (the current depends only on the voltage values at previous times) and the integral rapidly converges for reasonable voltage inputs. In practice usually $\eta>0$, but the integral converses even if $\eta < 0$.
I haven't been able to find this result in literature so far (I only found the Fourier transformed solution in most books), so I wanted to ask if this is correct and if so, is it known?
Edit: it just occurred to me that checking if (2) is correct is very easy: I just need to substitute this into telegraph equations and see it obeys them. I'll get back and edit once I manage that.
Edit 2: I now confirmed that (2) is correct by direct substitution.

you should show how you got the Eq.(1)

@hyportnex, it's lengthy. I could, but why? My question is asking for a reference (if a formula like that exists or not and if it does, is it the same as mine). The steps for obtaining that inverse Fourier transform are too lengthy to put in this post. I can give a short description of the method

You can find your (correct) formula here for example: Green’s function

@LPZ, thank you for the reference, I didn't think Wikipedia had this info

Just in case, the Green’s function is more general, for your problem, just set $x=0$. There are some good references in the bibliography
